# Sublime Text 4 node_modules go to definition, typescript/node

Tags: sublimetext

Is there a way to configure Sublime Text 4 so that the Go To Definition context menu item works for imports/requires?

I'm not having any issues with the go to definition for things defined myself, but when trying to view the imported module type definitions. Looking for behavior similar to VSCode's with this, or at least alternative but similar end result behavior.

This is on a clean install of ST4, node_modules is not in any exclude path in the settings.

Comment: Have you added the `node_modules` folder to your project? Go to Definition indexes the entire project (minus whatever you have explicitly excluded from indexing).

Comment: I think this was roundabout the issue. Looks like there is a "index_exclude_gitignore": true, obviously node_modules is in my gitignore, setting that to false and now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to set the "index_exclude_gitignore": false to get ST4 to index the node_modules folder to get this behavior working.